# Default role mapping when creating a MSSQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to set up a default set of role mappings for Microsoft SQL Server (2008 R2 for instance) that apply to subsequent databases?

Example: Whenever I create a new database on the server, I want it to map db_owner to a login group called Group_A and db_datareader to a group called Group_B.

The databases are created by a 3rd party application, so doing it in the CREATE statement is not enough. What I hope for is to set a default behaviour for the server itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every new database is created as a copy of the model database on the SQL server. So when you do the mapping the the MODEL db every new DB should replicate that. I haven't tried that with roles and groups but you can try it and let me know whether it works...